# Get rawValue from enum in a generic function

Tags: swift, reflection, enums

**Update 8/28/2015:**
This will be solved in Swift 2

See [Twitter response from Swift compiler developer](https://twitter.com/evermeer/status/636791736191320064)

**Update 10/23/2015:**
With Swift 2 generics you still cannot get the rawValue. You do can get the associated value.

**Original question:**

I have some [generic reflection code](https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection) written in swift. In that code I'm having trouble getting the value for properties that are based on an enum. The problem comes down to the fact that I'm not able to execute the `.rawValue` on the property value which is of type `Any`. The Swift reflection code will return the enum's value as type `Any`. So how can I get from an Any to an AnyObject which is the rawValue of the enum.

The only workaround i found so far is extending all enum's with a protocol. Below you can see a unit test that's OK using this workaround.

Is there any way to solve this without adding code to the original enum's?

for my reflection code I need the `getRawValue` method signature to stay as it is.

```
class WorkaroundsTests: XCTestCase {
    func testEnumToRaw() {
        let test1 = getRawValue(MyEnumOne.OK)
        XCTAssertTrue(test1 == "OK", "Could nog get the rawvalue using a generic function")
        let test2 = getRawValue(MyEnumTwo.OK)
        XCTAssertTrue(test2 == "1", "Could nog get the rawvalue using a generic function")
        let test3 = getRawValue(MyEnumThree.OK)
        XCTAssertTrue(test3 == "1", "Could nog get the rawvalue using a generic function")
    }


    enum MyEnumOne: String, EVRawString {
        case NotOK = "NotOK"
        case OK = "OK"
    }

    enum MyEnumTwo: Int, EVRawInt {
        case NotOK = 0
        case OK = 1
    }

    enum MyEnumThree: Int64, EVRaw {
        case NotOK = 0
        case OK = 1
        var anyRawValue: AnyObject { get { return String(self.rawValue) }}
    }

    func getRawValue(theEnum: Any) -> String {
        // What can we get using reflection:
        let mirror = reflect(theEnum)
        if mirror.disposition == .Aggregate {
            print("Disposition is .Aggregate\n")

            // OK, and now?

            // Thees do not complile:
            //return enumRawValue(rawValue: theEnum)
            //return enumRawValue2(theEnum )

            if let value = theEnum as? EVRawString {
                return value.rawValue
            }
            if let value = theEnum as? EVRawInt {
                return String(value.rawValue)
            }
        }
        var valueType:Any.Type = mirror.valueType
        print("valueType = \(valueType)\n")
        // No help from these:
        //var value = mirror.value  --> is just theEnum itself
        //var objectIdentifier = mirror.objectIdentifier   --> nil
        //var count = mirror.count   --> 0
        //var summary:String = mirror.summary     --> "(Enum Value)"
        //var quickLookObject = mirror.quickLookObject --> nil

        let toString:String = "\(theEnum)"
        print("\(toString)\n")
        return toString
    }

    func enumRawValue<E: RawRepresentable>(rawValue: E.RawValue) -> String {
        let value = E(rawValue: rawValue)?.rawValue
        return "\(value)"
    }

    func enumRawValue2<T:RawRepresentable>(rawValue: T) -> String {
        return "\(rawValue.rawValue)"
    }

}

    public protocol EVRawInt {
        var rawValue: Int { get }
    }
    public protocol EVRawString {
        var rawValue: String { get }
    }
    public protocol EVRaw {
        var anyRawValue: AnyObject { get }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to make it so complicated when you can just use `MyEnumOne.OK.rawValue` ?!

Comment: No I can't, that's the point. Im working on the reflection library https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection That library will have no knowledge about the enum that is defined by the app that is using the library. The only thing I have now is the enum value in a field of type Any. I cannot cast the Any to something else and the Any does not have a .rawValue

Comment: I don't know the language but how about something like: (is instanceof enum) -> for (values()) ...

Comment: That won't work. I get the value as an Any. I can not cast it to anything because an enum does not have a base type and I don't know the real enum type.

Comment: You won't be able to solve this thinking like that.  Any is [Top](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Top_(Logic)) in Swift, so you can prove every type is Any but you can't ever prove any is a specific type (Any is all types) without unsafeBitCast.  There needs to be at least 1 common protocol you can have your implementors adopt that gives you enough information to make a safe call.

Comment: @CodaFi, there is a common protocol. It's `RawRepresentable`. However, because `RawRepresentable` has an associated type (`RawValue`), you can't cast it to the protocol. That's just an unfortunate shortcoming of Swift, at least at this point.  You have to use a generic function with these protocols with associated types, but you can't pass an `Any` to a generic function and expect it to work with the correct concrete type.  The Swift compiler needs to know at compile-time what specialized version of the generic function to use, and just passing an `Any` doesn't give it enough type information.

Comment: Exactly.  What you're asking for is SYB in a language that doesn't allow you the leeway to hide all of the mechanics and acrobatics real generic programming generates behind the scenes.  You can bandy an `Any` around all day, but the function you generate won't be correct without further support from either you or the compiler.

Comment: when I execute a reflect on that any and look at it's valueType, then it will have the type of the original enum. So the compiler does know what it is. To bad there is no way to cast it to RawRepresentable. Adding my own protocol as in the sample looks as the minimal what's needed to make this work. I have looked at unsafeBitCast but then i need to know the underlying type (Int, Int64, ..)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, this doesn't look like it's possible in Swift at this point, but I've thought about your problem for a while, and I'll propose 3 ways that the Swift team could enable you to solve this problem.

1. **Fix the mirror for enums.** The most straightforward solution is one that I'm sure you already tried.  You're trying to build a reflection library, and you'd like to reflect an `Any` value to see if it's an enum, and if it is, you'd like to see if it has a raw value.  The `rawValue` property *should* be accessible via this code:

   ```
   let mirror = reflect(theEnum) // theEnum is of Any type
   for i in 0..<mirror.count {
       if mirror[i].0 == "rawValue" {
           switch mirror[i].1.value {
           case let s as String:
               return s
           case let csc as CustomStringConvertible:
               return csc.description
           default:
               return nil
           }
       }
   }
   ```

However, this doesn't work. You'll find that the mirror has a `count` of `0`.  I really think that this is an oversight on the part of the Swift team in their implementation of `Swift._EnumMirror`, and I'll be filing a radar about this.   `rawValue` is definitely a legitimate property. It is a weird scenario because enums aren't allowed to have other stored properties.  Also, your enum's declaration never explicitly conforms to `RawRepresentable`, nor does it declare the `rawValue` property.  The compiler just infers that when you type `enum MyEnum: String` or `: Int` or whatever.  In my tests, it appears that it shouldn't matter whether the property is defined in a protocol or is an instance of an associated type, it should still be a property represented in the mirror.

2. **Allow for protocol types with defined associated types.** As I mentioned in my comment above, it's a limitation in Swift that you cannot cast to a protocol type that has associated type requirements.  You can't simply cast to `RawRepresentable` because Swift doesn't know what type the `rawValue` property will return.  Syntax such as `RawRepresentable<where RawValue == String>` is conceivable, or perhaps `protocol<RawRepresentable where RawValue == String>`.  If this were possible, you could try to cast to the type through a switch statement as in:

   ```
   switch theEnum {
   case let rawEnum as protocol<RawRepresentable where RawValue == String>:
      return rawEnum.rawValue
   // And so on
   }
   ```

But that's not defined in Swift.  And if you just try to cast to `RawRepresentable`, the Swift compiler tells you that you can only use this in a generic function, but as I look at your code, that's only led you down a rabbit-hole.  Generic functions *need* type information at compile-time in order to work, and that's exactly what you don't have working with `Any` instances.

The Swift team could change protocols to be more like generic classes and structs.  For example `MyGenericStruct<MyType>` and `MyGenericClass<MyType>` are legitimately specialized concrete types that you can make a runtime check on and cast to.  However, the Swift team may have good reasons for not wanting to do this with protocols.  Specialized versions of protocols (i.e. protocol references with known associated types) still wouldn't be concrete types.  I wouldn't hold my breath for this ability.  I consider this the weakest of my proposed solutions.

3. **Extend protocols to conform to protocols.**  I really thought I could make this solution work for you, but alas no.  Since Swift's built-in mirror for enums doesn't deliver on the `rawValue`, I thought why not implement my own generic mirror:

   ```
   struct RawRepresentableMirror<T: RawRepresentable>: MirrorType {
       private let realValue: T

       init(_ value: T) {
           realValue = value
       }    

       var value: Any { return realValue }
       var valueType: Any.Type { return T.self }
       var objectIdentifier: ObjectIdentifier? { return nil }
       var disposition: MirrorDisposition { return .Enum }
       var count: Int { return 1 }

       subscript(index: Int) -> (String, MirrorType) {
           switch index {
           case 0:
               return ("rawValue", reflect(realValue.rawValue))
           default:
               fatalError("Index out of range")
           }
       }

       var summary: String {
           return "Raw Representable Enum: \(realValue)"
       }

       var quickLookObject: QuickLookObject? {
           return QuickLookObject.Text(summary)
       }
   }
   ```

Great!  Now all we have to do is extend `RawRepresentable` to be `Reflectable` so that we can first cast `theEnum as Reflectable` (no associated type required) and then call `reflect(theEnum)` to give us our awesome custom mirror:

```
    extension RawRepresentable: Reflectable {
        func getMirror() -> MirrorType {
            return RawRepresentableMirror(self)
        }
    }
```

> Compiler error: Extension of protocol 'RawRepresentable' cannot have
>   an inheritance clause

Whaaaat?!  We can extend concrete types to implement new protocols, such as:

```
    extension MyClass: MyProtocol {
        // Conform to new protocol
    }
```

As of Swift 2, we can extend protocols to give concrete implementations of functions, such as:

```
    extension MyProtocol {
        // Default implementations for MyProtocol
    }
```

I thought for sure we could extend protocols to implement other protocols, but apparently not!  I see no reason why we couldn't have Swift do this.  I think this would very much fit in with the protocol-oriented programming paradigm that was the talk of WWDC 2015.  Concrete types that implement the original protocol would get a new protocol conformance for free, but the concrete type is also free to define its own versions of the new protocol's methods.  I'll definitely be filing an enhancement request for this because I think it could be a powerful feature.  In fact, I think it could be very useful in your reflection library.

**Edit:** Thinking back on my dissatisfaction with answer 2, I think there's a more elegant and realistic possibility for working with these protocols broadly, and that actually combines my idea from answer 3 about extending protocols to conform to new protocols.  The idea is to have protocols with associated types conforming to new protocols that retrieve type-erased properties of the original.  Here is an example:

```
protocol AnyRawRepresentable {
    var anyRawValue: Any { get }
}

extension RawRepresentable: AnyRawRepresentable {
    var anyRawValue: Any {
        return rawValue
    }
}
```

Extending the protocol in this way wouldn't be extending inheritance per se.  Rather it would be just saying to the compiler "Wherever there is a type that conforms to `RawRepresentable`, make that type also conform to `AnyRawRepresentable` with this default implementation." `AnyRawRepresentable` wouldn't have associated type requirements, but can still retrieve `rawValue` as an `Any`.  In our code, then:

```
if let anyRawEnum = theEnum as? AnyRawRepresentable {  // Able to cast to
    let anyRawValue = anyRawEnum.anyRawValue  // anyRawValue is of type Any
    switch anyRawValue {
    case let s as String:
        return s
    case let csc as CustomStringConvertible:
        return csc.description
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

This kind of solution could be used broadly with any kind of protocol with associated types.  I will likewise be including this idea in my proposal to the Swift team for extending protocols with protocol conformance.

**Update**: None of the above options are available as of Swift 4.  I did not receive a response as to why the `Mirror` on a `RawRepresentable` enum does not contain its `rawValue`.  As for options #2 and #3, they are still within the realm of possibility for future releases of Swift.  They have been mentioned on the Swift mailing list and in the [Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md) document authored by Doug Gregor of the Swift team.

The proper term for option #2 ("Allow for protocol types with defined associated types") is [*generalized existentials*](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#generalized-existentials).  This would allow protocols with associated types to possibly automatically return `Any` where there is an associated type or allow for syntax like the following:

```
anyEnum as? Any<RawRepresentable where .RawValue == String>
```

Option #3 has been mentioned occasionally on the mailing list, and it is a commonly rejected requested feature, but that is not to say it couldn't be included in future versions of Swift.  In the Generics Manifesto, it is termed ["Conditional conformances via protocol extensions"](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#conditional-conformances-via-protocol-extensions).  While recognizing its power as a feature, it sadly also states that efficient implementation is "nearly impossible."

Comment: Thanks, that's a great thorough answer. Although it does not solve my problem, I think it's the right one.

Comment: I also created 2 enhancement requests (22103825 and 22103844 )

Comment: Thanks, @EdwinVermeer.  Rewarding the bounty was very generous of you, despite my not solving your problem.  I enjoyed pouring over this problem.

Comment: This will be solved in Swift 2.

See Twitter response from Swift compiler developer:  https://twitter.com/evermeer/status/636791736191320064

Comment: @EdwinVermeer any idea on how to get `rawValue` from Mirror? The first response to this tweet hints that this should now be possible

Comment: @DannieP Unfortunately using only Mirror you still can not get the rawValue from an Enum. To solve this issue I created a RawEnum protocol. If you extend your enum with that, then it's possible to get the rawValue. See the sample code here: https://github.com/evermeer/Stuff#enum I use that same technique in EVReflection

Comment: Swift 3 still has for 2nd : Extension of protocol 'RawRepresentable' cannot have an inheritance clause

Comment: @ChristopherWhidden has situation changed with release of Swift 4?

Comment: @IgorMuzyka Sadly no.  See the update in my answer for some details.

Comment: It is now possible with Swift 5.7, see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Great news!

Since Swift 5.6 you can now use `any` keyword to do exactly that.

It allows casting to a Protocols with associatedtypes like so:

```
enum Option: String {
    case a = "OptionA", b = "OptionB"
}

let theEnum: Any = Option.a

if let theRawEnum = theEnum as? (any RawRepresentable) {
    print("RawValue: \(theRawEnum.rawValue)")
}
```