# if-let Any to RawRepresentable<String>

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

Let's assume this:

```
enum MyEnum: String { case value }
let possibleEnum: Any = MyEnum.value
if let str = stringFromPossibleEnum(possibleEnum: possibleEnum)
```

What's my best bet of implementing `stringFromPossibleEnum` without knowing enum type name?

```
func stringFromPossibleEnum(possibleEnum: Any) -> String? {
//    how should this be implemented without knowing enum type name?
}
```

**UPD:** ok, it's getting better, with this I can tell if `possibleEnum` is an enum:

```
if Mirror(reflecting: possibleEnum).displayStyle == .enum { print("yes!") }
```

But how to tell if that's a `String`-based enum?

**UPD:** [this tweet](https://twitter.com/evermeer/status/636791736191320064) suggests that you can get `rawValue` as Any from Enum. You can probably then check if that `rawValue` is `String`. But how to get `rawValue` from `Mirror`?

Comment: I am smelling [`XY`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem here. What are you _exactly_ trying to do?

Comment: I'd like to know this side of `swift` better.

Comment: `var a: Any? = str.rawValue` should work just as fine but I am not sure if this is what you want because you are not telling us about what you are really trying to do.

Comment: let me rework the question so that it is more clear

Comment: If you just know `a` is just a string-backed enum, and not specifically *what* enum it is, it's not possible (AFAIK) to get the backed value (all you know is it is `RawRepresentable` but you can't declare something as a `RawRepresentable` because of protocol associatedtypes). As @OzgurVatansever said, this sounds like you've already started to go down the wrong path a bit.

Comment: @ConnorNeville that's exactly what I'm looking for - how to get raw value out of `String`-based `RawRepresentable`. I tried to do this straight way, but obviously it did not work as PATs are somehow different.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever pure interes is the reason.

Comment: `let str = "\(possibleEnum)"`

Comment: @vacawama Thank you. This is cool, that's some progress. Now need to figure out how to tell if that `Any` contains enum \ string-based RawRepresentable.

Comment: @DannieP I think this answer contains information you might find useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31759324/773625

Comment: @mAu thank you. Updating the answer based on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so this is basically not doable currently out of the box, as you can't `as?`-cast to `RawRepresentable`, and `Mirror` does not provide `rawValue` for enums.

I'd say the best bet is to make own `protocol`, provide default implementation for `String`-based `RawRepresentable` and conform all enums manually like so:

Assuming these are the enums:

```
enum E1: String { case one }
enum E2: String { case two }
enum E3: String { case three }
```

`StringRawRepresentable` protocol and default implementation:

```
protocol StringRawRepresentable {
    var stringRawValue: String { get }
}

extension StringRawRepresentable 
where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == String {
    var stringRawValue: String { return rawValue }
}
```

Conform all needed existing enums to the protocol:

```
extension E1: StringRawRepresentable {}
extension E2: StringRawRepresentable {}
extension E3: StringRawRepresentable {}
```

And now we can cast to `StringRawRepresentable`:

```
func stringFromPossibleEnum(possibleEnum: Any) -> String? {
    if let e = possibleEnum as? StringRawRepresentable { return e.stringRawValue }
    return nil
}

stringFromPossibleEnum(possibleEnum: E2.two as Any)
```

Comment: problem of this answer is that you should extend every enum. That's monkey job.

Comment: @Aleksandr that's true. Let me know if you have a solution that involves less monkey-job then this one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're really trying to achieve here, but here it is:

```
enum MyEnum: String {
    case A
    case B
    case C
}

func stringFromEnum<T: RawRepresentable>(_ value: T) -> String
    where T.RawValue == String {
    return value.rawValue
}

print(stringFromEnum(MyEnum.A))
print(stringFromEnum(MyEnum.B))
print(stringFromEnum(MyEnum.C))
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your response. If you can get `stringFromEnum` to accept `Any` and return `String` if passed value is a String RawRepresentable - that's what I was interested in

Answer (score 0):

Based on Danni P's answer

```
enum E1: String { case one }
enum E2: String { case two }
enum E3: String { case three }


func stringFromPossibleEnum(possibleEnum: Any) -> String? {
    if let e = possibleEnum as? (any RawRepresentable),
       let str = e.rawValue as? String {
        return str
    }
    return nil
}

stringFromPossibleEnum(possibleEnum: E2.two as Any)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).