# How I can get rawValue from enum, if element is Any?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have a variable of type `Any?`. I'm totally know what that variable is type of `enum: String`. How I can get rawValue something like:

```
var somevar: Any? = someValue
(somevar as ?????).rawValue
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952248/get-all-enum-values-as-an-array. See this post I hop helps to you

Comment: If you *totally* know that the variable is a `String` enum, why do you declare it as `Any`? You are fighting the strong type system. Be always as specific as possible not the contrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have this defined somewhere in your or in imported module:

```
enum First: String {
    case a, b
}

enum Second: String {
    case c, d
}
```

In you module your should do something like this:

```
protocol StringRawRepresentable {
    var rawValue: String { get }
}

extension First: StringRawRepresentable {}
extension Second: StringRawRepresentable {}
```

And here's your problem:

```
var somevar: Any? = someValue
let result = (somevar as? StringRawRepresentable)?.rawValue
```

If, for example, `someValue == Second.c` you gonna get `"c"` in `result`.

This approach will work, but you will have to `extend` all the possible types, otherwise `as?` casting will result in `nil` even if type has `rawValue: String` property.

Comment: Seems this is equivalent to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43868223/6541007).

Comment: @OOPer, protocol names do match, rest is just trivial usage of language features, less complex that in that linked answer.

Comment: You can have your own opinion. But I cannot find any significant difference than the linked answer or the answer of Prashant Tukadiya. And yours is two minutes later than Prashant Tukadiya's.

Comment: @OOPer earlier*

Comment: @OOPer, so what's your point? That I've plagiarised answer? Time `X ago` works in reverse, bigger the X, earlier it was posted.

Answer (score 1):

First of all sorry I misunderstood your question.

**Yes it is possible  and very EASY**

it is beauty of swift

You have to add some extra step there

**Step1 :**

Add protocol

```
protocol TestMe {
    var rawValueDesc: String {get}
    
}
```

**Step 2 :**

In your enum  implement it

```
 enum YourEnum:String,TestMe {
        case one = "test"
        case two = "test1"
        
        var rawValueDesc: String {
            return self.rawValue
        }
        
    }
```

**Finally**

```
    var testdd:Any = YourEnum.one
    if let finalValue =   testdd as? TestMe {
       print( finalValue.rawValueDesc)
    }
```

Hope it is helpful to you